# How do I export more complex node set-ups from blender to godot?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, export, eevee-render-engine

I created this energy core for a friend to use in a game. It has animations on it and everything.

[image]

Everything is exporting as it should but not the material that I need. This is the node setup for it:

[image]

I used EEVEE for this in new blender 2.8, and instead of my node setup it only exports the material as Principled BSDF with emission. And that looks like this:

[image]

So my question is, is there a way to export this material how it was intended or there is no way to do that?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541

Comment: that is a **nice** material.  great job!

Comment: could you add a picture with the values of the nodes?

Comment: The procedural textures (noise, musgrave, magic, etc.) are special int the fact that they are vector, so they will never seem low res.  this is not possible in game engines, so if you want to export the texture, you'll have to bake the procedural textures first.

Comment: Godot uses its own way of creating Materials/Shader optimised for its own use and there is no conversion path from blender to it. But you have made a good prototype that should be easy to implement in Godot. Read up on Shader creation here https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/tutorials/shading/shading_language.html

Godot shaders is outside the scope for this forum.